# How to use loops to adjust path names

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, loops, csv

I'm working on a program which analyses a lot of csv files.
Currently I'm declaring every item manually, but as you can see in my code I'm actually just go +1 in my paths and in the variable-names.
I guess I can simplify this with a loop, just don't know how to do this with the path-names.

My code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np 

### declation ###
df_primes1 = pd.DataFrame()
df_primes1 = np.array(df_primes1)
df_search1 = pd.DataFrame()

df_primes2 = pd.DataFrame()
df_primes2 = np.array(df_primes2)
df_search2 = pd.DataFrame()

df_primes3 = pd.DataFrame()
df_primes3 = np.array(df_primes3)
df_search3 = pd.DataFrame()

searchterm = '322'

### reads csv in numpy array ###
df_primes1 = pd.read_csv('1/1_Primes_32.csv', delimiter=';', header=None, names='1')
df_primes2 = pd.read_csv('1/2_Primes_32.csv', delimiter=';', header=None, names='2')
df_primes3 = pd.read_csv('1/3_Primes_32.csv', delimiter=';', header=None, names='3')

### sorts prime numbers ###
#df_sorted = df_primes1.sort_values(by='n')
#print(df_sorted)


### searches for number with "searchterm" as start value ###
df_search1 = df_primes1[df_primes1['1'].astype(str).str.startswith(searchterm)]['1']
df_search2 = df_primes2[df_primes2['2'].astype(str).str.startswith(searchterm)]['2']
df_search3 = df_primes3[df_primes3['3'].astype(str).str.startswith(searchterm)]['3']


print(df_search1)
print(df_search2)
print(df_search3)
```

The program is working, I was just want to know how I can simplify this, because there will be 20+ more files like this.

Comment: do you know of the path modules in Python from the standard lib? namely `pathlib` and `os` you can get all the paths with a simple `glob` call - `from pathlib import Path;Path(your_path).glob('*Primes*.csv')` or something like that `;` is a newline here this returns a generator you can turn it into a list with `[file for file in Path()...]`

Comment: Thanks for the fast answer. 
How can I seperate that each csv file is written to another dataframe?

Comment: do you want to read all files and stored each in different dataframe and search for specific column like if you read file `1/3_Primes_32.csv` than you want to search the string in 3rd columns and print it., is that right?

Comment: I want to write each file in a different dataframe. After that I want to do the same analysis to all data frames (e.g. search for number starting with 322) and print the output of each data frame. The output looks like this:
```33        3223402517
74        3229416881
129       3227514877
```

Answer (score 1):

IIUC, we can use pathlib and a dict comprehension :

```
from pathlib import Path

p = 'Path/to/your_csv/'

dfs = {
    f"search_{i}": pd.read_csv(file, delimiter=";", 
                                     header=None, 
                                     names=str(i))
    for i, file in enumerate(Path(p).glob("*Prime*.csv"), 1)
}
```

to break down each item,

`p` is the target folder that holds your csvs

`i` is an enumerator to loop over your files you *will most likely* need to add a pre-step of sorting your csvs to get the order you're after.

`file` is each item that is returned from the generator object. we turn each value into a dataframe.

you can filter each dataframe by your collection i.e

```
dfs['search_1']
```

this will return a dataframe.

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but get the error:
```dfs['search_1']
KeyError: 'search_1' ```

Comment: @SaveOurPlanet `print(dfs.keys())`

Comment: Now I receive: 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  …/test_file.py", line 20, in <module>
    for i, file in enumerate(Path(p).glob("*Primes_32.csv"), 1)
  …/test_file.py", line 20, in <dictcomp>
    for i, file in enumerate(Path(p).glob("*Primes_32.csv"), 1)
  …/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 676, in parser_f
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
   …/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 445, in _read
    _validate_names(kwds.get("names", None))
  …/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 413, in _validate_names
    raise ValueError("Duplicate names are not allowed.")